# Problem with the responsiveness of a branched treeview when displayed on mobile screens

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5

```js
    $.fn.extend({
        treed: function (o) {

          var openedClass = 'fa-minus-circle';
          var closedClass = 'fa-plus-circle';

          if (typeof o != 'undefined'){
            if (typeof o.openedClass != 'undefined'){
            openedClass = o.openedClass;
            }
            if (typeof o.closedClass != 'undefined'){
            closedClass = o.closedClass;
            }
          };

            //initialize each of the top levels
            var tree = $(this);
            tree.addClass("tree");
            tree.find('li').has("ul").each(function () {
                var branch = $(this); //li with children ul
                branch.prepend("<i class='indicator fas " + closedClass + "'></i>");
                branch.addClass('branch');
                branch.on('click', function (e) {
                    if (this == e.target) {
                        var icon = $(this).children('i:first');
                        icon.toggleClass(openedClass + " " + closedClass);
                        $(this).append("<div class='loading'><span class='fa fa-spinner fa-spin'</span></div>");         
                          setTimeout(()=>{
                            $(this).find('.loading').remove();
                            $(this).children().children().slideToggle(400);
                          }, 400)
                    }
                })
                branch.children().children().toggle();
            });
            //fire event from the dynamically added icon
          tree.find('.branch .indicator').each(function(){
            $(this).on('click', function () {
                $(this).closest('li').click();
            });
          });
            //fire event to open branch if the li contains an anchor instead of text
            tree.find('.branch>a').each(function () {
                $(this).on('click', function (e) {
                    $(this).closest('li').click();
                    e.preventDefault();
                });
            });
            //fire event to open branch if the li contains a button instead of text
            tree.find('.branch>button').each(function () {
                $(this).on('click', function (e) {
                    $(this).closest('li').click();
                    e.preventDefault();
                });
            });
        }
    });

    //Initialization of treeviews

    $('#tree1').treed();
$.fn.extend({
  treed: function (o) {

    var openedClass = 'fa-minus-circle';
    var closedClass = 'fa-plus-circle';

    if (typeof o != 'undefined'){
      if (typeof o.openedClass != 'undefined'){
      openedClass = o.openedClass;
      }
      if (typeof o.closedClass != 'undefined'){
      closedClass = o.closedClass;
      }
    };

//initialize each of the top levels
      var tree = $(this);
      tree.addClass("tree");
      tree.find('li').has("ul").each(function () {
          var branch = $(this); //li with children ul
          branch.prepend("<i class='indicator fas " + closedClass + "'></i>");
          branch.addClass('branch');

          // declare a flag to toggle
          let flag = false;
          branch.on('click', function (e) {
              if (this == e.target) {
                  // toggle on click
                  flag = !flag;
                  var icon = $(this).children('i:first');
                  icon.toggleClass(openedClass + " " + closedClass); 

                  // show loader only when its opened, and collpase once toggled   
                  if(flag) {
                    $(this).append("<div class='loading'><span class='fa fa-spinner fa-spin'</span></div>"); 
                    setTimeout(()=>{
                      $(this).find('.loading').remove();
                      $(this).children().children().slideToggle(400);
                    }, 400)
                  } else {
                    $(this).children().children().slideToggle(400);
                  }
              }
          })
          branch.children().children().toggle();
      });

//fire event from the dynamically added icon
    tree.find('.branch .indicator').each(function(){
      $(this).on('click', function () {
          $(this).closest('li').click();
      });
    });
      //fire event to open branch if the li contains an anchor instead of text
      tree.find('.branch>a').each(function () {
          $(this).on('click', function (e) {
              $(this).closest('li').click();
              e.preventDefault();
          });
      });
      //fire event to open branch if the li contains a button instead of text
      tree.find('.branch>button').each(function () {
          $(this).on('click', function (e) {
              $(this).closest('li').click();
              e.preventDefault();
              });
          });
      }
    });
    
    //Initialization of treeviews
    
    $('#tree1').treed();
    
    $('#tree2').treed({openedClass:'fa-folder-open', closedClass:'fa-folder'});
```

```css
    .tree, .tree ul {
      margin:0;
      padding:0;
      list-style:none;
      margin-left:10px;
    }
    .tree ul {
      margin-left:1em;
      position:relative
    }
    .tree ul ul {
      margin-left:.5em
    }
    .tree ul:before {
      content:"";
      display:block;
      width:0;
      position:absolute;
      top:0;
      bottom:0;
      left:0;
      border-left:1px solid
    }
    .tree li {
      margin:0;
      padding:0 1em;
      line-height:2em;
      color:#369;
      font-weight:700;
      position:relative;
    }
    .tree ul li:before {
      content:"";
      display:block;
      width:10px;
      height:0;
      border-top:1px solid;
      margin-top:-1px;
      position:absolute;
      top:1em;
      left:0
    }
    .tree ul li:last-child:before {
      background:#fff;
      height:auto;
      top:1em;
      bottom:0
    }
    .indicator {
      margin-right:5px;
    }
    .tree li a {
      text-decoration: none;
      color:#369;
    }
    .tree li button, .tree li button:active, .tree li button:focus {
      text-decoration: none;
      color:#369;
      border:none;
      background:transparent;
      margin:0px 0px 0px 0px;
      padding:0px 0px 0px 0px;
      outline: 0;
    }

    .loading {
      font-style: italic;
    }
.timeline {
  border-left: 1px solid hsl(0, 0%, 90%);
  position: relative;
  list-style: none;
}

.timeline .timeline-item {
  position: relative;
}

.timeline .timeline-item:after {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  top: 0;
}

.timeline .timeline-item:after {
  background-color: hsl(0, 0%, 90%);
  left: -38px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  height: 11px;
  width: 11px;
  content: "";

}
```

```html
  

<section class="content">


  <div class="container-fluid">


  <div class="card">


    <div class="card-body">              


      <div class="row">


        <div class="col-md-4">


        <ul id="tree2">


          <li>


          <a href="#">TECH</a>


          <ul>


            <li>Company Maintenance</li>


            <li>


              Employees


              <ul>


                <li>


                Reports


                <ul>


                  <li>Report1


                  <ul>


                  <li>Report1


                  <ul>


                  <li>Report1


                  <ul>


                  <li>Report1</li>


                  <li>Report2</li>


                  <li>Report3</li>


                </ul>


                  </li>


                  <li>Report2</li>


                  <li>Report3</li>


                </ul>


                  </li>


                  <li>Report2</li>


                  <li>Report3</li>


                </ul>


                  </li>


                  <li>Report2</li>


                  <li>Report3</li>


                </ul>


                </li>


                <li>Employee Maint.</li>


              </ul>


            </li>


            <li>Human Resources</li>


          </ul>


          </li>


             </ul>


      </div>        


      </div>


   </div>


  <div class="card-footer text-body-secondary">


</div> 


</div>  <!-- /.container-fluid -->


   </section>


                    
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.1/dist/css/bootstrap.rtl.min.css">
   <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.7.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-lZN37f5QGtY3VHgisS14W3ExzMWZxybE1SJSEsQp9S+oqd12jhcu+A56Ebc1zFSJ" crossorigin="anonymous">
<!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-HwwvtgBNo3bZJJLYd8oVXjrBZt8cqVSpeBNS5n7C8IVInixGAoxmnlMuBnhbgrkm" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.js"></script>
```

I have a treeview with several internal branches that work well on large computer screens, but the problem I am facing is that when I display it on mobile phone screens, it appears very poorly and completely uncoordinated. The letters also appear very fragmented and irregular. Please help me with the necessary formatting and adjustments to make the treeview work smoothly on mobile screens. I will include the captured images when displayed on computer screens and mobile screens to show the problem I am facing.
[image: desktop]
[image: mobile]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, apparently it cannot fit the screen, so you might make it a scrollable container with overflow (for the `tree` container) and without text wrapping (for the `branch`es):

```
.tree {
  overflow-x: auto;
}

.branch {
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```js
$.fn.extend({
        treed: function (o) {

          var openedClass = 'fa-minus-circle';
          var closedClass = 'fa-plus-circle';

          if (typeof o != 'undefined'){
            if (typeof o.openedClass != 'undefined'){
            openedClass = o.openedClass;
            }
            if (typeof o.closedClass != 'undefined'){
            closedClass = o.closedClass;
            }
          };

            //initialize each of the top levels
            var tree = $(this);
            tree.addClass("tree");
            tree.find('li').has("ul").each(function () {
                var branch = $(this); //li with children ul
                branch.prepend("<i class='indicator fas " + closedClass + "'></i>");
                branch.addClass('branch');
                branch.on('click', function (e) {
                    if (this == e.target) {
                        var icon = $(this).children('i:first');
                        icon.toggleClass(openedClass + " " + closedClass);
                        $(this).append("<div class='loading'><span class='fa fa-spinner fa-spin'</span></div>");         
                          setTimeout(()=>{
                            $(this).find('.loading').remove();
                            $(this).children().children().slideToggle(400);
                          }, 400)
                    }
                })
                branch.children().children().toggle();
            });
            //fire event from the dynamically added icon
          tree.find('.branch .indicator').each(function(){
            $(this).on('click', function () {
                $(this).closest('li').click();
            });
          });
            //fire event to open branch if the li contains an anchor instead of text
            tree.find('.branch>a').each(function () {
                $(this).on('click', function (e) {
                    $(this).closest('li').click();
                    e.preventDefault();
                });
            });
            //fire event to open branch if the li contains a button instead of text
            tree.find('.branch>button').each(function () {
                $(this).on('click', function (e) {
                    $(this).closest('li').click();
                    e.preventDefault();
                });
            });
        }
    });

    //Initialization of treeviews

    $('#tree1').treed();
$.fn.extend({
  treed: function (o) {

    var openedClass = 'fa-minus-circle';
    var closedClass = 'fa-plus-circle';

    if (typeof o != 'undefined'){
      if (typeof o.openedClass != 'undefined'){
      openedClass = o.openedClass;
      }
      if (typeof o.closedClass != 'undefined'){
      closedClass = o.closedClass;
      }
    };

//initialize each of the top levels
      var tree = $(this);
      tree.addClass("tree");
      tree.find('li').has("ul").each(function () {
          var branch = $(this); //li with children ul
          branch.prepend("<i class='indicator fas " + closedClass + "'></i>");
          branch.addClass('branch');

          // declare a flag to toggle
          let flag = false;
          branch.on('click', function (e) {
              if (this == e.target) {
                  // toggle on click
                  flag = !flag;
                  var icon = $(this).children('i:first');
                  icon.toggleClass(openedClass + " " + closedClass); 

                  // show loader only when its opened, and collpase once toggled   
                  if(flag) {
                    $(this).append("<div class='loading'><span class='fa fa-spinner fa-spin'</span></div>"); 
                    setTimeout(()=>{
                      $(this).find('.loading').remove();
                      $(this).children().children().slideToggle(400);
                    }, 400)
                  } else {
                    $(this).children().children().slideToggle(400);
                  }
              }
          })
          branch.children().children().toggle();
      });

//fire event from the dynamically added icon
    tree.find('.branch .indicator').each(function(){
      $(this).on('click', function () {
          $(this).closest('li').click();
      });
    });
      //fire event to open branch if the li contains an anchor instead of text
      tree.find('.branch>a').each(function () {
          $(this).on('click', function (e) {
              $(this).closest('li').click();
              e.preventDefault();
          });
      });
      //fire event to open branch if the li contains a button instead of text
      tree.find('.branch>button').each(function () {
          $(this).on('click', function (e) {
              $(this).closest('li').click();
              e.preventDefault();
              });
          });
      }
    });
    
    //Initialization of treeviews
    
    $('#tree1').treed();
    
    $('#tree2').treed({openedClass:'fa-folder-open', closedClass:'fa-folder'});
```

```css
.tree {
  overflow-y: auto;
}
.branch {
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.tree, .tree ul {
      margin:0;
      padding:0;
      list-style:none;
      margin-left:10px;
    }
    .tree ul {
      margin-left:1em;
      position:relative
    }
    .tree ul ul {
      margin-left:.5em
    }
    .tree ul:before {
      content:"";
      display:block;
      width:0;
      position:absolute;
      top:0;
      bottom:0;
      left:0;
      border-left:1px solid
    }
    .tree li {
      margin:0;
      padding:0 1em;
      line-height:2em;
      color:#369;
      font-weight:700;
      position:relative;
    }
    .tree ul li:before {
      content:"";
      display:block;
      width:10px;
      height:0;
      border-top:1px solid;
      margin-top:-1px;
      position:absolute;
      top:1em;
      left:0
    }
    .tree ul li:last-child:before {
      background:#fff;
      height:auto;
      top:1em;
      bottom:0
    }
    .indicator {
      margin-right:5px;
    }
    .tree li a {
      text-decoration: none;
      color:#369;
    }
    .tree li button, .tree li button:active, .tree li button:focus {
      text-decoration: none;
      color:#369;
      border:none;
      background:transparent;
      margin:0px 0px 0px 0px;
      padding:0px 0px 0px 0px;
      outline: 0;
    }

    .loading {
      font-style: italic;
    }
.timeline {
  border-left: 1px solid hsl(0, 0%, 90%);
  position: relative;
  list-style: none;
}

.timeline .timeline-item {
  position: relative;
}

.timeline .timeline-item:after {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  top: 0;
}

.timeline .timeline-item:after {
  background-color: hsl(0, 0%, 90%);
  left: -38px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  height: 11px;
  width: 11px;
  content: "";

}
```

```html
<section class="content">


  <div class="container-fluid">


  <div class="card">


    <div class="card-body">              


      <div class="row">


        <div class="col-md-4">


        <ul id="tree2">


          <li>


          <a href="#">TECH</a>


          <ul>


            <li>Company Maintenance</li>


            <li>


              Employees


              <ul>


                <li>


                Reports


                <ul>


                  <li>Report1


                  <ul>


                  <li>Report1


                  <ul>


                  <li>Report1


                  <ul>


                  <li>Report1</li>


                  <li>Report2</li>


                  <li>Report3</li>


                </ul>


                  </li>


                  <li>Report2</li>


                  <li>Report3</li>


                </ul>


                  </li>


                  <li>Report2</li>


                  <li>Report3</li>


                </ul>


                  </li>


                  <li>Report2</li>


                  <li>Report3</li>


                </ul>


                </li>


                <li>Employee Maint.</li>


              </ul>


            </li>


            <li>Human Resources</li>


          </ul>


          </li>


             </ul>


      </div>        


      </div>


   </div>


  <div class="card-footer text-body-secondary">


</div> 


</div>  <!-- /.container-fluid -->


   </section>


                    
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.1/dist/css/bootstrap.rtl.min.css">
   <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.7.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-lZN37f5QGtY3VHgisS14W3ExzMWZxybE1SJSEsQp9S+oqd12jhcu+A56Ebc1zFSJ" crossorigin="anonymous">
<!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-HwwvtgBNo3bZJJLYd8oVXjrBZt8cqVSpeBNS5n7C8IVInixGAoxmnlMuBnhbgrkm" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you, great answer. Do I need to padding the treeview a little to the left or is it not necessary?

Comment: well, it depends on the whole layout and design, but removing padding/margins would add more space, so yeah, it should be useful. Try it and see how it looks, I think you can remove `margin-left: 10px;` from `.tree`, that should move it to the left a bit, and you might use [BS utilities](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.2/utilities/spacing/), add `p-0` on `card-body`, but that's now fine tuning